# How to bring the output of a cut-command into a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, variables, command, cut

This is a question for a Linux bash-shell-script.

I would like to bring the output of a "cut-command" into a variable. But it does not work. The variable remains empty.

Here is what I did:

```
MyName@MyName:~
$ fixedFilePath=aa.zz
MyName@MyName:~
$ echo $fixedFilePath
aa.zz
MyName@MyName:~
$ EP=$fixedFilePath | rev | cut -d '.' -f 1 | rev
MyName@MyName:~
$ echo $EP

MyName@MyName:~
$
```

As you can see: Nothing is in the variable $EP now. My expectation was, that in $EP is now "zz".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign to `EP`, the first section, `$fixedFilePath` leaves nothing on stdout for the pipe to take. What it does is executes the contents of that variable. You need to `echo`.

`echo $fixedFilePath | rev | cut -d '.' -f 1 | rev`

Now to capture that output you need to execute it as part of the assignment. There are various ways to go about this but what I found worked in your case was surrounding it in [backticks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands):

```
EP=`echo $fixedFilePath | rev | cut -d '.' -f 1 | rev`
```